# Intercept close button in Qt console app

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, console

I am writing a console server in Qt. I have to run a function when the app is closing however I tried connection to QCoreApplication's aboutToQuit signal but it doesn't get emitted when I press the x on the top of the console. What is a good multiplatform way to run a function just as the console app is about to exit.

Comment: your title does not match your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try to use a function "atexit" from C Library. See more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app call qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true) ?  If so, the app.exec() call should return when you close the last window, and therefore you could just put a call to your function at the bottom of main().

Comment: Since the OP is talking about a console application, there will not be any windows.

Comment: Hmm, I was confused by the mention of a 'close button' in the question title; I thought he meant an application that implemented a text console.